# Batch script find process PID

Tags: c#, batch-file

I'm working on a tool to kill a process if it's cmd command line contains a very specific keywords.

I wrote a small program using C# but it failed on some legacy systems that does not have .NET installed.

I need your help for any hints or snippets to covert my c# code to a batch script.

Thank you a lot

```
public static int GetSysmonLockerProcess()
        {
            try
            {
                var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT Name, CommandLine, ProcessId, Caption, ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process");
                var collection = searcher.Get();

                foreach (var o in collection)
                {
                    var obj = (ManagementObject)o;

                    var type = obj["Process"]?.ToString().ToLower();
                    var commandLine = obj["CommandLine"]?.ToString();
                    var procId = obj["ProcessId"]?.ToString().ToLower();
                    var name = obj["Name"]?.ToString().ToLower();

                    int.TryParse(procId, out var pid);
                    if (pid == 0)
                        continue;

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(commandLine))
                        continue;

                    if (name == "cmd.exe" && type == "process" && commandLine.Contains("TA-Sysmon-deploy") && commandLine.Contains("SplunkUniversalForwarder") && (commandLine.Contains("deploy.bat") || commandLine.Contains("deploy2.bat")))
                        return pid;
                }

                return -1;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should be able to retrieve the information you need using the WMIC utility. Here's a single line batch file command example for you to test or use as your basis: `@WMIC Process Where "CommandLine Like '%%TA-Sysmon-deploy%%' And CommandLine Like '%%SplunkUniversalForwarder%%' And CommandLine Like '%%deploy.bat%%' And Name='cmd.exe' Or CommandLine Like '%%TA-Sysmon-deploy%%' And CommandLine Like '%%SplunkUniversalForwarder%%' And CommandLine Like '%%deploy2.bat%%' And Name='cmd.exe'" Call Terminate`. Please note that this assumes that your legacy systems are at least, XP Pro/Server 2003.

Comment: Please also be aware that this site is not supposed to answer code requests, or convert code between languages for people. Your question is off topic until you have written your own code, and edited your question to show it, and explain where it is failing to do what was required of it.

Answer (score 1):

As a batchfile line,

```dos
for /f "tokens=2" %%P in ('tasklist /v ^|findstr /b /i /L /c:"cmd.exe "^|findstr /i /L /c:"wd5"') do echo taskkill /PID %%P
```

Where  `wd5` is the string I used as a target, simply because I happen to have a `cmd` process on my system with that string as its parameter.

The `echo` just causes the proposed `taskkill` command to be presented on the console. Remove said `echo` keyword to execute `taskkill` once you have confirmed that the procedure reliably selects the correct PIDs.

The `tasklist/v` command produces a (`/v`) verbose list of the current tasks. The first `findstr` finds those lines that `/b` begin with the `/L` literal string `/c:` constant string (as it deliberately includes spaces) *"that is in quotes"* `/i` -case-**I**nsensitive.

The next `findstr` selects remaining lines that contain the keyword `wd5`.

The pipes are escaped by `^` to tell `cmd` that are part of the `'single-quoted command to be executed'`, not of the enclosing `for`.

The `for` processes any lines that emerge from the `'quoted command'`, tokenises it using the default delimiters (which include <kbd>space</kbd>) and assigns the second token to the metavariable `%%P` which is used as the command to `DO`.

So - no need whatever for C#-heresy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code i wrote that will do the thing

```
@echo off
cls
title Process_Killer
:loop
echo --------- Process_Killer ---------
echo 1: Show all Tasks
echo 2: Kill Task by PID
echo 3: Kill Task by name
echo 4: Exit
set choice=
set /p choice=Choice:
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='1' goto show_tasks
if '%choice%'=='2' goto kill_by_pid
if '%choice%'=='3' goto kill_by_name
if '%choice%'=='4' goto Exit
goto error
:show_tasks
tasklist
pause 
:kill_by_pid
set pid=
set /p pid=Enter PID:
taskkill /F /PID %pid%
goto loop
:kill_by_name
set name=
set /p name=Enter process name:
taskkill /im %name% /f
goto loop
:Exit
exit
:error
echo Error:Unidentified input
goto loop
```